# Functional tests for flash messages after redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, redirect, functional-testing

I'm not sure how to check flash messages with functional tests.  My problem has something to do with `redirect_to` because my test for `flash[:error]` DOES pass.  Here is what my `create` action looks like:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, flash: { success: "Welcome!" }
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Signup failed:"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

I have a passing test for `flash[:error]` that 1) checks that `flash[:error]` is the correct value, 2) checks the page for the flash div, and 3) gets a new page and checks that the flash message has been cleared.  I tried to make an analogous test for `flash[:success]` but it is failing when it tries to find the div on the page.  Here is the failing test:

```
  should "show flash[:success] message" do
    post :create, user: { name: "valid user",
                          password: "userpw",
                          password_confirmation: "userpw",
                          email: "a@b.com" }        
    assert_redirected_to user_path(assigns(:user)), "user isn't being redirected to their page after registration"
    assert_equal flash[:success], "Welcome!", "flash[:success] isn't being set properly"
    assert_select "div.alert-success", flash[:success]
    get :new
    assert flash.empty?, "there shouldn't be any flash messages left after getting new page"
  end
```

When I test this manually in a browser, it behaves as expected, but I'm not sure how to write the tests to reflect this.  The first two assertions are passing (so the test recognizes that it is being redirected correctly, and that `flash[:success]` is being set to `"Welcome!"`).  Based on that, I would think the `assert_select` statement would be able to find the div, but if fails with this error message:

```
Expected at least 1 element matching "div.alert-success", found 0.
```

So I tried adding `puts @response.body` right before the `assert_select` statement, which printed this:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://test.host/users/3">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

This explains why it couldn't find the flash div, but I'm not sure how to "finish" the redirect so that it renders the correct view with the flash div.  If I add a `get` statement right before the `assert_select` statement, the test passes, because now `@response.body` has the flash div.  However, this doesn't seem like an effective test because it doesn't reflect the behavior of my application - the user doesn't have to make a new request to see the flash message.

It also doesn't guarantee that the flash message shows up on the correct page.  If I use the statement `get :new`, the assertion still passes, which implies that the flash message would be present on the `users#new` view.  Even if I use

```
get :show, id: assigns(:user).id
```

to make sure the flash message shows up on the correct page, this still feels wrong because 1) now it is a `success` response instead of a `redirect` response, and 2) it still doesn't explain why I have to manually request ANY page to find the flash div - according to the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash), "The flash is a special part of the session which is **cleared with each request.**"

Anyway, is there a way to test that a flash message shows up correctly after a redirect?

Comment: I have the same issue. I found that when I redirect from an action invoked by get it seems to work, i.e. the assert_select has access to the redirected view, but when I redirect from an action invoked by 'post' it only sees the 'You are being redirected…' page. Very annoying. I tried to use follow_redirect! but this is not available in functional tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering this question from the POV that what you're trying to test would be better tested elsewhere. If you're having a lot of trouble setting up the test, odds are there's a better way to test it :)

1. Testing that flash messages get cleared - flash messages are built into Rails, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to test something that the framework is handling for you.
2. Testing that elements show up on the page - view specs don't belong in controllers. Here is a description of the role of the controller:

   > A controller can thus be thought of as a middle man between models and
   >   views. It makes the model data available to the view so it can display
   >   that data to the user.

   The controller is supposed to make data available to the view, not to specify how the data gets rendered. Imagine if you changed the name of your CSS class, then you'd have to also update your controller specs.

   If you really want to test that flash messages show up, I would use an integration test.