# Rspec 3 how to test flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test controller's action and flash messages presence with rspec.

**action**:

```
def create
  user = Users::User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if user
    user.send_reset_password_instructions
    flash[:success] = "Reset password instructions have been sent to #{user.email}."
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Can't find user with this email: #{params[:email]}"
  end

  redirect_to root_path
end
```

**spec**:

```
describe "#create" do
  it "sends reset password instructions if user exists" do
    post :create, email: "email@example.com"      
    expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
    expect(flash[:success]).to be_present
  end
...
```

But I've got an error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(flash[:success]).to be_present
   expected `nil.present?` to return true, got false
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You are testing for the presence of `flash[:success]`, but in your controller you are using `flash[:notice]`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just slipped here. 
Same error with flash[:notice]

Comment: In that case, the problem is probably with your controller code and/or test data. Try to change the `expect(flash[:notice])` to `expect(flash[:alert])`, and if the test passes then probably it's just that the test email doesn't exists.

Answer (score 54):

The best way to test flash messages is provided by the [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) gem.

Here are three examples:

```
expect(controller).to set_flash
expect(controller).to set_flash[:success]
expect(controller).to set_flash.now[:alert].to(/are not valid/)
```

Answer (score 43):

If you are more interested in the content of the flash messages you can use this:

```
expect(flash[:success]).to match(/Reset password instructions have been sent to .*/)
```

or

```
expect(flash[:alert]).to match(/Can't find user with this email: .*/)
```

I would advise against checking for a specific message unless that message is critical and/or it does not change often.

Answer (score 5):

With: `gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'`

The `.now` should be called directly on the `set_flash`.

Using `set_flash` with the `now` qualifier and specifying `now` after other qualifiers is no longer allowed.

You'll want to use `now` immediately after `set_flash`. For instance:

```
# Valid
should set_flash.now[:foo]
should set_flash.now[:foo].to('bar')

# Invalid
should set_flash[:foo].now
should set_flash[:foo].to('bar').now
```

Answer (score 2):

The another approach is to leave out the fact that a controller has flash messages and write an integration test instead. This way you increase chances that you will not need to alter the test once you decide to show that message using JavaScript or by some other way.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897912/2987689