# Rails 5.1 syntax to test flash message in a system test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Do you know the syntax for testing a flash message using system tests?

This is how I'm currently writing it...

```
test 'New User signup' do
  # ...
  click_button 'Create User'
  assert_equal 'User was successfully created.', flash[:notice]
end
```

The failing test screenshot shows the flash is there but the test fails with

`` NoMethodError: NoMethodError: undefined method `flash' for nil:NilClass ``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up changing the assertion from:

```
assert_equal 'User was successfully created.', flash[:notice]
```

to:

```
assert_selector "#notice", text: 'User was successfully created.'
```

which seemed to do the trick.

Comment: here are other ways to test flash messages with rspec and shoulda (quite old but still valid):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919976/rspec-3-how-to-test-flash-messages

Comment: @StandardNerd not really relevant if you are doing Rails 5 integration tests - not controller tests.

Comment: What you're doing is the "right" way. Instead of poking in the internals you are actually testing page as the user sees it.